# Завершающий слеш laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url, route

Есть юрл страницы site/fr , site/de и пр.
Когда прописываешь site/fr или site/fr/ получается дублирование страницы.
Как через `Route` или другими способом добавать(редирект на страницу со) слеш.  Например ввел site/fr а тебе выдало страницу site/fr/ , через htaccess не вариант так как он добавит всем адресам слеш, а мне не нужно чтобы только когда выбор языка, потому что далее site/fr/page выглядит юрл без слеша.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае будет эффективно создать middleware `php artisan make:middleware DontEndSlashMiddleware` и добавить его в список посредников группы `web` в файле `app/Http/Kernel.php`.
В методе `handle` вновь созданного посредника написать алгоритм 301 редиректа для страниц с закрывающим слешем

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $uri = $request->getRequestUri();

    if($uri != '/' && $uri[strlen($uri)-1] == '/'){
        return redirect(substr($uri,0,strlen($uri)-1),301);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Данный посредник будет проверять, оканчивается ли `REQUEST_URI` на slash или нет, конечно же не учитывая главную страницу. Если есть закрывающий slash, то произойдет редирект на эту же страницу без закрывающего слеша

Comment: Так нужно же наоборот, чтобы если язык то закрывался слэш